# dash/plotly: how to change the font size of label and value in dash_daq.Gauge

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I had written the below code using plotly documentation . But not able to change the font size of label and the middle value

```
app.layout = html.Div([daq.Gauge(
                            id='my-gauge-1',
                            label="Max",
                            value=61,
                            showCurrentValue=True,
                            color = {"gradient":True,"ranges":{"green":[0,30],"yellow":[30,60],"red":[60,80]}},
                            max=80,
                            size=400,
                            style = {
                            "align": "center",
                            "display": "flex",
                            "marginTop": "5%",
                            "marginBottom": "20%",
                            'font':'70'
                            },
                        )],style={'width': '40%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'padding': '0 
                                                                   0','height' : '20px})])
```

Output of this code is below figure. How to change the font size of text lable and middle values of the gauge?

[image]

Thank you in advance..!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the label as follow:

```
app.layout = html.Div([daq.Gauge(id='my-gauge-1',
                                 label={"label":"Max", "font-size":"20px"},
                                 value=61,
                                 showCurrentValue=True,
                                 color = {"gradient":True,"ranges":{"green":[0,30],"yellow":[30,60],"red":[60,80]}},
                                 max=80,
                                 size=400,
                                 style = {
                                     "align": "center",
                                     "display": "flex",
                                     "marginTop": "5%",
                                     "marginBottom": "20%",
                                     'font':'70'
                                 },)],
                                 style={'width': '40%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'padding': '0','height' : '20px})])
```